# Merge non tracked changes into repository (crash recovery)

Tags: mercurial, merge, tortoisehg, recovery

I just used Zero Assumption Recovery to recover my hg repositories of my crashed development box.  My `.hg` directories seem to (not surprisingly) be messed up.  I get errors on `hg status` like:

- Unknown format
- Everything is listed as an unknown file.  The repo itself is empty.
- No repository found

I have less recent copies of all these repos on my server anyways... is there a way to use mercurial to track down the differences between the most recent commit on the server and the recovered files so I can rebuild as much as possible?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out its *remarkably* simple, as I thought it would be.

I copied the `.hg` directory from my most recent commit on the server into the recovered instance from the crashed HD.

Now when I run `hg status`, it shows me the differences between the server version and the recovered version.  Once I've cleaned it all up, I'll push it back to the server and I'll have a recovered repo (at least as much as I'm going to get).